# PHP iframe abrindo mais de uma sessao para o mesmo navegador

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estou trabalhando em um sistema de adsense, e na mesma página possui vários iframes chamado, o problema é que preciso limitar a quantidade para cada pagina
só que pelo acesso ser muito rápido ele cria uma sessao para cada iframe, fiz um contador porem não resolve pois para cada sessao ele estará no 0 sempre.Eu uso o cookie do navegador para dar um tempo de vida a sessao, por quando o usuário atualizar a página precisa renovar a quantidade.

```
$cookie = $this->input->cookie('token');
    $hash_cookie = substr($this->input->get('wg', TRUE), 0,20);
    if(empty($cookie)){
        $this->input->set_cookie(['name' => 'token', 'value' => random_string('alpha', 6),'expire' => 5]);
        unset($_SESSION['hashs']);
        $_SESSION['hashs'] = [];

    }
    if(empty($_SESSION['hashs'][$hash_cookie])){
        $_SESSION['hashs'][$hash_cookie] =  0;
    }
    if($_SESSION['hashs'][$hash_cookie] < 3)
        $_SESSION['hashs'][$hash_cookie] += 1; 
    else 
        return '';
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Foi necessário colocar um setTimeout no javascript para fazer as requisições pois minhas sessões estavam sendo salvas em arquivos por isso a lentidão em atualizar.